# QUrl containing parentheses

Tags: windows-7, qt4

Our application is a 32 bit application. When it is installed in windows 7 64bit, typically it installs at “C:\Program Files (x86)”, instead of “C:\Program Files”. We are constructing a Url based on the install location and pass it around as part of a web service. We are constructing the Url like this:

```
ppmPath = "http://" + ipAddress + ":13007/" + folder + ".ppm" + "?filePath="
          + applicationDirPath + "/" + FIRMWARE;
QUrl ppmURL( ppmPath, QUrl::TolerantMode );
ppmPath = QString( ppmURL.toEncoded() );
```

The variable types and meaning are usual.

Since “applicationDirPath” for Windows 7 64 bit contains one closing bracket “)” - in the “(x86)” substring – apparently the URL is broken. If we install it to any other location, it works perfectly, even though the location has any other special character.

How to deal with “)” character in the URL, so that is is not broken?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qurl.html#ParsingMode-enum) it doesn't look like parentheses are automatically encoded by QUrl, even in tolerant mode. If you first wrap your URL in a QString and then replace all `(` characters with "%28" and all `)` characters with "%29" then it should behave like you expect.

```
QString ppmPath = QString("http://" + ipAddress + ":13007/" + folder + ".ppm" + "?filePath="
          + applicationDirPath + "/" + FIRMWARE);
QUrl ppmURL( ppmPath, QUrl::TolerantMode );
ppmPath = QString( ppmURL.toEncoded() );
ppmPath.replace(QChar('('), "%%28");
ppmPath.replace(QChar(')'), "%%29");
```

I'm not 100% sure the double-% needs to be there, but I remember having trouble with that in the past. Try it both ways.

Alternatively, you could try playing with [QUrl::toPercentEncoding()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qurl.html#toPercentEncoding) and skip the constructor altogether. It appears to convert parentheses.

```
QUrl ppmURL(QString("http://" + ipAddress + ":13007/" + folder + ".ppm"), QUrl::TolerantMode );
QString filepath = QUrl::toPercentEncoding(applicationDirPath + "/" + FIRMWARE);
ppmUrl.addEncodedQueryItem("filepath", filepath.toLocal8Bit());
ppmPath = QString( ppmURL.toEncoded() );
```